# Script guard without indenting execution code

Tags: python, python-3.x

`if __name__ == '__main__':` prevents any code beneath it from executing in any non-main script (e.g. imports) - however, it requires all pertinent code to be indented. Is there an alternative to not executing code beneath that line, *without* indenting said code?

```py
if __name__ != '__main__':
    sys.exit(0)
do_stuff()  # <-- NOT indented
```

Something like above, except without terminating the entire program.

Comment: No, there is not. If it's really important, but the code in a separate .py file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking for either a "stop importing here" statement or a  clean way to avoid Python's rules about indentation. No, neither are feasible. If you don't want `do_stuff()` to be executed at import time, your choices are to put it under the `if` block or to comment it out or to remove it from the file.